# Modify the parameters of the Wave Modifier

Tags: animation, modifiers

I am working on this animation and losing my sanity.

I would like the waves to make ripples that die out in half a second.

But unfortunately no matter what I do, the ripples go on and bounce off the edge of the pool object. I've tried modifying the settings of the Wave modifier, and deleting/redoing the bake, nothing has worked.

[image]

Comment: after you delete your bake; on your "piscine" physics properties increase your damping to something between 0.15 and 0.3

Comment: @Ratt i think part of the problem is that there are parameters for Wave in both the modifier tab and in the Physics tab. They seem independent from each other

Comment: the settings in the modifier panel are for the standing wave (not the wet paint map) the settings in the physics panel are with regards to the interaction with the wetmap. The damping will affect the amplitude over time so once you have that set to die off in the proper frame count you can adjust the speed which will affect the wave propagation outward to a distance you desire.

Answer (score 1):

### Shader Method

You could use a mask that defines a gradient over your object and use a *Math* node set to *Multiply* to mix with a *Wave Texture*.

[image]

Then the timing comes down to how fast your *Phase Offset* value is animated, and the range of your gradient, which can be controlled with a *Color Ramp*.

[image]

Many ways to arrange this to get the control you want.

[image]

[image]